# How to use PHP to get the *idex* of the selected combobox item, not its text?

Tags: php, forms

If I have a combobBox with values `red/white/blue` and the users chooses `blue` then I want my form action php page to use the value 2, not `blue. I hope you see what I mean.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Whatever is in the `value` attribute of the selected `<option>` tag will be present in the `$_POST` array, and not the text between the two `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action='phpPage.php' name='bsForm' method='POST'>
<select name='TheColor' onSelect="bsForm.submit()">
   <option value='0'>red</option>
   <option value='1'>white</option>
   <option value='2'>blue</option>
</select>
</form>
```

If your form looks anything like that, then your phpPage should easily be able to get the value 2 from $_POST['TheColor']

Comment: d'oh!  My values were red/white/blue :-)

Answer (score 5):

You do this by constructing your form appropriately and supplying a `value` attribute:

```
<option value="2">blue</option>
```